# LLVM,Fail to create call instruction by LLVM IRBuilder class

Tags: llvm

I want to write a simple frontend for language PL/0,the lexer and parser seems work well,but there has a bug when generating call statement LLVM IR.

Here is my code for generating IR for the PL/0 call statement: `CALL ident`. It fails to execute the `Builder.CreateCall(F,None,"calltmp");`

The console says:

```
pl0: /root/llvm-6.0/lib/IR/Value.cpp:247: 
void llvm::Value::setNameImpl(const llvm::Twine&): 
Assertion `!getType()->isVoidTy() && "Cannot assign a name to void values!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The `TheModule->getFunction()` gets the correct function. All functions in my implementation has function type `void ..()`, no return value and no argument.

I tried to debug it with `gdb`; it seems the instruction created by `Builder.CreateCall(...)` is "optimized out".

What's wrong with this?

Code for generating call statement:

```
bool CallStatAST::codegen()
{
    auto F = TheModule->getFunction(Callee);
    if(!F)
    logErrorL("Failing to get function from module at  CallStatAST::codegen()!\n");

    //std::vector<Value*> Args;
    Builder.CreateCall(F,None,"calltmp");
    return true;
}
```

`gdb` debug information:

```
1. (gdb) break 391 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4713a5: file pl0.cpp, line 391.
2. (gdb) run < test1.pl0 
Starting program: /root/my_llvm/PL0/pl0 < test1.pl0
3. Breakpoint 1, get (this=optimized out) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../include/c++/4.8.5/bits/unique_ptr.h:234
234       { return std::get<0>(_M_t); }

4. (gdb) n
CallStatAST::codegen (this=0xa165d0) at pl0.cpp:392
392     auto F = TheModule->getFunction(Callee);
5. (gdb) p F->dump()

            define internal void @myfun() 
            {
                entry:
                %i = alloca double
                %a = load double, double* @a
                %b = load double, double* @b
                %addtmp = fadd double %a, %b
                store double %addtmp, double* %i
                ret void
            }
            $1 = void
6. (gdb) p F->getName()
$2 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, Data = 0xa17310 "myfun", Length = 5}
(gdb) n
397     Builder.CreateCall(F,None,"calltmp");

7. (gdb) s
Twine (Str=0xa17278 "\300P\241", this=optimized out) at /usr/local/include/llvm/ADT/Twine.h:270
270         LHS.cString = Str;

8. (gdb) n
CallStatAST::codegen (this=optimized out) at pl0.cpp:397
397     Builder.CreateCall(F,None,"calltmp");
```

Comment: Please... do not format your posts like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How fool I am!
I unbelievable want to assign a name to a void return value,there does not have a value and how can set a name for it?
convert:

```
Builder.CreateCall(F,None,"calltmp");
```

to:

```
Builder.CreateCall(F,None);
```

all things work again!

Comment: me too! thanks for solving Builder.CreateCall(let_func, {chan_function->arg_begin()});